# Failed to send event with message "Server has been disposed" but the server keeps accepting other events

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have an application that uses Apache ActiveMQ as its event broker. While processing one event, it attempt to send a second event, but the second event failed with the message indicating that the server has been disposed.

In the second where this error occurred, my broker accepted 4 before this error, and it accepted 6 messages after this error (all within the same second). It continued to run another 7 seconds (where we processed probably 100 or so events) before logging this error again. When the message was logged for a second time, the broker accepted 27 other messages before this error and 42 messages afterwards (again, all within the same second).

We are using a Spring JmsTemplate to send the messages.

```
Caused by: de.dser.event.exceptions.EventServiceException: Server has been disposed.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportServer.connect(VMTransportServer.java:69)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory.doCompositeConnect(VMTransportFactory.java:150)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory.doConnect(VMTransportFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:331)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:346)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:494)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584)
```

The message is sent using the following code

```
        final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerService.getVmConnectorURI());
        final JmsTemplate jms = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        jms.send(queueName, session -> {
            final Message message = session.createObjectMessage(event);
            message.setStringProperty("name", eventName);
            return message;
        });
```

What can cause this error? The server is not shutting down or restarting. It continues to process the vast majority of messages with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the exception message say, "Server has been disposed," it's not talking about the entire instance of ActiveMQ. It's only talking about the instance of the `org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportServer` the client is using to make a VM connection to the broker. I recommend you activate DEBUG logging for `org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory`. That might shed some light on what's happening behind the scenes.

Aside from that, I strongly recommend that you change the way you're using the JMSTemplate to send messages. As [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html) states:

> The thing to remember is JmsTemplate is designed for use in EJBs using the EJB containers JMS pooling abstraction. So every method will typically create a connection, session, producer or consumer, do something, then close them all down again. The idea being that this will use the J2EE containers pooling mechanism to pool the JMS resources under the covers. Without using a pooled JMS provider from the EJB container this is the worst possible way of working with JMS; since typically each create/close of a connection, producer/consumer results in a request-response with the JMS broker.

Instead of creating and passing an instance of `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` directly to the JMSTemplate I recommend you use a single instance of a pooled connection factory implementation.

Comment: Problem hasn't occurred since we changed to a pooled connection as you suggested. Thanks for the help!